# Can we say the "Adir bamarom" prayer after the prayer which we say instead of "Birkat Kohanim"?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, birchas-kohanim

Extracted from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/894569/jewish/The-Priestly-Blessing.htm):

The prevailing custom in the Diaspora to relegate the *Birkat Kohanim* to the major holidays.
After *Birkat Kohanim*, the congregation silently recites the short *Adir bamarom* prayer.

When *Birkat Kohanim* is not performed, the *chazzan* recites the short prayer, **in lieu** of *Birkat Kohanim*, "Our G d and G d of our fathers, bless us with the threefold blessing written in the Torah by Moses Your servant, and pronounced by Aaron and his sons the Kohanim… [and the prayer concludes with the text of the Priestly Birkat Blessing]."

Is there a source for saying the Adir bamarom prayer after the **in lieu** prayer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure! The Rama recommends saying it every day (for those who don't say the full Birkat Kohanim every day) after the **in lieu** prayer. [Shulchan Aruch OC 130:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C)

Comment: And this is many people's practice also.